# Does installing a terminal emulator from play store root my phone?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, android-emulator

I recently Termux terminal emulator in my phone to copy files from my phone to my mac through a ssh connection. But I fear whether installing such emulators root of damage the OS.

Comment: Simple answer - **No**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all, a terminal is just a command-line utiity useful for executing shell commands, that might otherwise be difficult to input without such a utility, or alternatively can be achieved using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) via your PC.

On the other hand, rooting involves putting (and modifying) the `su` binary (that previously didn't exist in the device) giving appropriate permissions, in order to allow certain apps/proceses to execute with elevated privileges.

Furthermore a terminal app can even be used to carry out normal tasks that doesn't require root.